# How can I iterate over a numpy multidimensional array of dataframes?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, loops

Im trying to iterate over a multidimensional array on Python but I'm having problems because my array is full of dataframes instead of int().

I have a multidimensional numpy array (12, 11) which contains 12 x 11 different dataframes.

```
nombres_df =            np.array([[df_01_ID4034, df_02_ID4034, df_03_ID4034, df_04_ID4034, df_05_ID4034, df_06_ID4034, df_07_ID4034, df_08_ID4034, df_09_ID4034, df_10_ID4034, df_11_ID4034, df_12_ID4034], 
                         [df_01_ID4035, df_02_ID4035, df_03_ID4035, df_04_ID4035, df_05_ID4035, df_06_ID4035, df_07_ID4035, df_08_ID4035, df_09_ID4035, df_10_ID4035, df_11_ID4035, df_12_ID4035], 
                         [df_01_ID4039, df_02_ID4039, df_03_ID4039, df_04_ID4039, df_05_ID4039, df_06_ID4039, df_07_ID4039, df_08_ID4039, df_09_ID4039, df_10_ID4039, df_11_ID4039, df_12_ID4039], 
                         [df_01_ID4040, df_02_ID4040, df_03_ID4040, df_04_ID4040, df_05_ID4040, df_06_ID4040, df_07_ID4040, df_08_ID4040, df_09_ID4040, df_10_ID4040, df_11_ID4040, df_12_ID4040],
                         [df_01_ID4041, df_02_ID4041, df_03_ID4041, df_04_ID4041, df_05_ID4041, df_06_ID4041, df_07_ID4041, df_08_ID4041, df_09_ID4041, df_10_ID4041, df_11_ID4041, df_12_ID4041],
                         [df_01_ID4042, df_02_ID4042, df_03_ID4042, df_04_ID4042, df_05_ID4042, df_06_ID4042, df_07_ID4042, df_08_ID4042, df_09_ID4042, df_10_ID4042, df_11_ID4042, df_12_ID4042],
                         [df_01_ID4047, df_02_ID4047, df_03_ID4047, df_04_ID4047, df_05_ID4047, df_06_ID4047, df_07_ID4047, df_08_ID4047, df_09_ID4047, df_10_ID4047, df_11_ID4047, df_12_ID4047],
                         [df_01_ID4049, df_02_ID4049, df_03_ID4049, df_04_ID4049, df_05_ID4049, df_06_ID4049, df_07_ID4049, df_08_ID4049, df_09_ID4049, df_10_ID4049, df_11_ID4049, df_12_ID4049],
                         [df_01_ID4056, df_02_ID4056, df_03_ID4056, df_04_ID4056, df_05_ID4056, df_06_ID4056, df_07_ID4056, df_08_ID4056, df_09_ID4056, df_10_ID4056, df_11_ID4056, df_12_ID4056],
                         [df_01_ID4059, df_02_ID4059, df_03_ID4059, df_04_ID4059, df_05_ID4059, df_06_ID4059, df_07_ID4059, df_08_ID4059, df_09_ID4059, df_10_ID4059, df_11_ID4059, df_12_ID4059],
                         [df_01_ID4075, df_02_ID4075, df_03_ID4075, df_04_ID4075, df_05_ID4075, df_06_ID4075, df_07_ID4075, df_08_ID4075, df_09_ID4075, df_10_ID4075, df_11_ID4075, df_12_ID4075]], dtype="object")
```

```
for j in range(len(nombres_df)): 
    for i in range(len(nombres_df[i])):
        print (nombres_df[i][j])
```

I need to iterate over it and make operations with values inside each dataframe.
The problem is that when I try to iterate as usually, I cannot do it because I'm getting this error:

> ```
>  5 
>  6 for j in range(len(nombres_df)):
>  7     for i in range(len(nombres_df[i])):    <--------
>  8         print (nombres_df[i][j], end = " ")
> ```
>
> IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type

I know the problem is here `len(nombres_df[i])` but I don`t know how to solve it.

Thank you very much

Comment: `for i in range(len(nombres_df[i]))` is bogus because the right part reference `i` which is the iterator that is dependent of the right part... You certainly mean `j`. Besides, please use `your_array.shape[1]` instead of `len(your_array[i])`. Also note that `nombres_df[i][j]` is not efficient in a `i`-based loop because of strided acces and also because of the double view (consider at least using `nombres_df[i,j]`). More generally, iterating over Numpy array with loops is not a good idea as it is slow. You should use vectorized operation.

Comment: Please consider reading the tutorial: https://numpy.org/learn/ (or the many other sources of documentation).

Comment: Thank you for you response, it was very useful. 

Do you know why when I do a print(nombres_df[0][0]) at the end of the nested loop, the output should be nombres_df[0][0] position, which should be just one dataframe. Instead of that, I get nombres_df[0][0] position repeated multiple times, not just one. It seems like is accessing the position multiple times and showing it as an output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thick the problem is the fact that you are iterating over the wrong index in the second line of your code.
that `i` inside `range(len(nombres_df[i]))` shoud be `j`

also you inverted the indexes in `nombres_df[i][j]` it shoud be `nombres_df[j][i]`

this shoud do the trick

```
for j in range(len(nombres_df)): 
    for i in range(len(nombres_df[j])):
        print (nombres_df[j][i])
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. The problem is now solved but when I want to print just one position like *print(nombres_df[0][0])*, the output is that position repeated multiple times. 
Any way to solve it?

Comment: I dont undestand what you mean by  'the output is that position repeated multiple times' please clarify better

Comment: When I do a **print(nombres_df[0][0])** at the end of the nested loop, the output should be *nombres_df[0][0] position*, which should be just one dataframe. 

Instead of that, I get *nombres_df[0][0] position repeated multiple times, not just one*. It seems like is accessing the position multiple times and showing it as an output

Comment: thas because you are looping, loops are for iterating over multiple elements. if you need to print a single element why are you using loops in the first place? just call print(nombres_df[0][0]) outside once

Comment: I was doing tests to see how the loop behaved thats why I tryed with print(nombres_df[0][0]). Even if I'm inside a loop, if I only access position [0][0] it should return *ONE SINGLE value*, instead of the same value repeated several times, but it doesn't.

Comment: bro thats the problem that you are calling  print(nombres_df[0][0]) multiple times inside the loop